# Virus plaque assay, pfu/ml calculation on plates with too little plaques formed

Tags: microbiology, virology

I am a student, so I hope it is okay to put this question here. I've done the virus plaque assay in a practical recently and have a few questions regarding the plaque count for pfu calculation.

In the plates corresponding to times 0 and 10 mins, a few plaques formed (less than 5 plaques in every plate where plaques could be seen) Should I still calculate pfu with those results, or should I leave it as 0 pfu, and use only plaque counts that are at least more than 10?

Comment: Wouldn't the actual number of plaque forming units be more precise? Would it make any if your following steps more difficult or why do you want to simplify it?

Comment: http://www.microbiol.org/resources/monographswhite-papers/counting-colonies/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by simplyging? We were told to count the plaques we could see in the petri dishes and calculate pfu from there. What I don't understand if I should calculate pfu even when there's only one plaque in the plate. The protocol says we should choose the plate that has 20 to 300 plaques for the calculation, but I cannot do that with the plates for time 0 and time 10, because all plates have less than 10 plaques in them. In plates of time 0 the maximum I have is 2 plaques. So I don't know whether it's okay to calculate pfu of 2 plaques or it is usually left out

Comment: What is the virus?  If, for example, it is a bacteriophage, then you would not expect any virus particles to be produced at those early time points, right?